# How to pass string in two dimension array using c

Tags: c

I have made one string using strcpy which looks as

```
char optarg ={"30","31"}
```

How to pass the optarg in array so it will  pass as `dest[3][3]={"30","31"}`

Comment: That code doesn't look valid. Please edit your question to include real code.

Comment: Please note that _an array of pointers is not a 2D array_. Also, you probably meant `cont char* optarg [] = {"30", "31"};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single string should not be of `char` type.

A string is basically equivalent to a `char*` type, so to make an array of strings, make your variable a `char**`. Your code should look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    //code to generate the strings here...

    char** optarg = //array of strings

    foo(optarg);
}

void foo(char** dest)
{
    //do stuff with dest
}
```

Comment: if we initialize the array statically  like,char optarg[3][3] = {"30","31","32"} or char optarg** ={"30","31","32"} then there is no issue and it works fine but while creating the array as shown in below snippet we can't pass the same by :optarg as it will require index to access the individual string.
char optarg[3][3]={0,};
strcpy(optarg[0],"31");
strcpy(optarg[1],"32");

Comment: @pri You either want an array of pointers or you want a 2D array. They are not the same and they are not compatible. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I mean ...main() {char send[3][3] = {"30","31","32"}; status = foo(send);} foo((char** res)){} EXEC SQL DECLARE abcd CURSOR FOR SELECT Consignment FROM Transaction WHERE order_type IN (:res) ; This gives only records for order_type =30 and skip 31,32